# UVA world reversal, why won't second array gain first array values?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* input  first array   second array*/
    char x, a[50] = {0, }, b[50] = {0, };
    /*  input into a       position in second array         first array to second*/
   int i = 0,             k = 0,                             j = 1;

    while(x=getchar()){
        if(x != ' ' && x != '\n'){
            /* input reading */
            a[i] = x;
            i++;
            printf("%s\n", a);
        }
        else if(x == ' ' || x == '\n'){
            /* when it finds whitespace it reverses the word and takes new word*/
            while(j > 0){
                j = i - k;
                b[k] = a[j]; /* this is the main problem */
                k++;
            }
            if(x == ' ')
                printf("%s ", b);
            else if(x == '\n')
                printf("%s\n", b)
            i = 0;
            k = 0;
            j = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code isn't completely ready in other regards aswell, but i would like to work on these parts myself, I'm just wondering how to manipulate arrays.
I'm more interested in how c works than right answers to this problem as it is schoolwork.

Comment: BTW c comments are between /* */ and not between \\* *\\.

Comment: And you should decompose the problem into smaller simpler parts instead of doing everything in the main function.

Comment: For starters, replace `||` by `&&` in `if(x != ' ' || x != '\n')`.

Comment: At the end you have to set `j = 1` instead of `j = 0`. Otherwise it just works for the first word.

Comment: To Ruud and honk, fixed what you suggested tyvm, but I still don't know how to give one array values to other array.

Comment: I used temporary char to keep values in middle of changin, i quess its some pointer action going on, i also used single array and got it done. Thank you to everyone who answered.